# How do I make my js file works for both ES6 modules and normal js?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I have a js file looks like this. I want this file works for both

`<script src="./foo.js"><script>`

and

`<script type="module" src="index.js"><script>`

---

### foo.js

```js
const foo = () => console.log('Hello World!');

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = foo;
}

export default foo;
```

### index.js

```js
import foo from './foo.js';

foo();
```

---

But this doesn't work, it gives me an error while I'm using `<script src="./foo.js"><script>` syntax to import my `foo.js`.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

Is there a way to make my `foo.js` works for both of the situations?

---

Here is [a repo contains these files on GitHub](https://github.com/wheatup/module-example).

Comment: That's a good question that I thought of as well. Unfortunately, it seems that currently there's no solution to it (as you can't put `export` in an `if` statement, and it causes error without it)...

Comment: @FZs I've also tried to put `export` into `try catch` / `eval` and it seems still doesn't work. Wish we have a new feature in ECMAScript that make a js file works in browser, ES6 modules and also node.js.

Comment: @HaoWu Yes, I agree. `export` statements are allowed only on the topmost scope (to allow static module analysis), so you can't put it in any block, such as `if` or `try..catch`. `eval` also won't work, as it evaluates the string as a Script, not as a Module. What would be good to have a feature like `export_if_module` that would export something if used inside a module, or would be no-op if used inside a script, and it would still allow static analysis...

Comment: TBH, the easiest fix I can imagine is to make js parser ignore `export` statements if the js file is imported normally, instead of throwing an error.

Comment: @HaoWu If you want to write one format that works both in the browser and in nodejs, the solution is to use ES6 modules. If you need it to work in non-module environments, use a transpiler for those.

Comment: "*I want both `<script type="module" src="foo.js">` and `<script src="foo.js">` to work*" - that's only possible if you write a file that doesn't have imports or exports.

Comment: Btw, ES6 modules *are* "normal js" :-)

Comment: @Bergi Well, by `normal js` I mean `non-module js`

Comment: I've always thought that it was a mistake for the ES committee to add a new syntax for this. Node.js did it right by making modules a design pattern instead of a new syntax - for one, you can actually use exports with `if` because the module is constructed by plain javascript code at runtime instead of at parse/compile time

Comment: I don't think this is so easily possible. But the following link explains a way: https://jorgeartieda.gitbook.io/typescript-from-namespaces-to-modules/introduction#simple-goal

Answer (score -2):

ES6 module doesn’t work on the `file://` protocol, you need to use [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) to run a server locally for testing.

And in your `index-normal.html`, you need to add `type="module"` and then import `foo()` in order to use `foo()` in the callback function.

```js
<script type="module">
    import foo from './foo.js';

    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        foo();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I think you misread the question: 1. there's no mention of `file://` protocol, 2. This still won't make the script work without ES6 modules